# How to push a notification to flutter app for IOS/android from asp.net mvc 5?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, asp.net-mvc-5

I’m building a car rental flutter application to let the users reserve a car and I'm building an asp.net admin side to accept the reservation or reject it so, I want when the admin takes this action I want to push notification to the user with the rejecting or the accepting ,so how I can do that without firebase?

I have tried Workmaneger flutter package to do that, but It's not working in IOS like what I want and it should be at least every 15 mins.

any idea how to do it like normal apps?

Comment: I think one way could be to create a websocket, but the drawback will be if the application is not running, user will not get notification.. It would be much easier with firebase.